# \textcite without square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I'm using Biber with fowlling options

```
\usepackage[backend = biber,style=bwl-FU, citestyle =authoryear-ibid, ibidpage, %siehe Doku 
 pagetracker=false,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{parentracker=false}
```

the `\textcite[p. 23]{LA}` creates "Large ((2012), p. 23)"
but I'd like to get "Large (2012), p. 23", is there a way to change the output of `\textcite`

Comment: Since I don't get the brackets twice, you should provide a MWE including your bib entry.

Comment: Is there something wrong with writing `\textcite{LA}, p.\ 23`?